# Ubuntu 14.04 - Flash Drives Not Working

Tags: usb

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 and now my flash drive don't even blink when plugged in. I know they work as I can see them on boot and on my other computer just fine.

The command "lsusb" just hangs and idles forever not returning anything.

Any ideas?

`$ lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 693.2G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   5.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

dmesg output is [here](http://pastebin.com/kXN4VCMh)

Comment: post the output of `lsblk` command.

Comment: Updated original post.

Comment: connect your USB drive and then run `lsblk` command. A second disk would appear just like `sdb` or `sdc`

Comment: That was with the USB drive plugged in.

Comment: did you able to run `lsusb` command?

Comment: I let that command run for almost an hour, but it just hangs.

Comment: This looks like some bigger issue. Could you please upload the output of `dmesg` (best: right after a reboot, before and after you plug the USB key) to pastebin and edit your question to include the link? Since dmesg outputs a lot of stuff, you should probably pipe the output to a file directly (eg `dmesg > somefile.txt`)

Comment: Does it work with a different USB drive?

Comment: Dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/kXN4VCMh Also, I did try other usb drives and had the same result.

Comment: Hi @soulsource I have the same issue, I did run dmesg and I am getting **can't set config #1, error -12** what is the problem

Comment: To exclude that this could be a hardware defect did you try to boot this machine form any of USB disks? Did you try to boot this machine from any Live CD and check from there whether you USB drives work or not?

Comment: @Waqleh This sounds like a hardware issue. I had similar issues when using the front USB ports of my computer, which obviously have a too high internal resistance. I'd suggest to try to use a powered USB hub or, if you were using the front USB ports, try to use the ports directly on the mainboard.

Comment: @soulsource tester the usb port on linux mint (dual boot) it works fin. it can't be a hardware issue

Comment: hardware issues often go through a period of inconsistency before failing utterly. I would not jump to this conclusion without further proof. Do you have other USB devices plugged into the same bus when testing on mint AND Ubuntu?

Comment: @Waqleh http://askubuntu.com/questions/276425/asus-xtion-pro-live-not-working-with-xhci-hcd sounds similar to your issue.

Comment: @Aucun please issue the command `tail /var/log/syslog` from the terminal and paste the output that occurs (both before and after you plug in the flash drive) into your question.

Comment: @Aucun check out syslog http://askubuntu.com/questions/485029/usb-flash-drive-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @ElderGeek All usb devices (mouse, keybored etc...) and ports work on my PC but what doesn't work is only usb flash and hard drives

Comment: @Waqleh why would your syslog be useful in answering Aucan question?

Comment: please provide the output of `uname -a`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your user was somehow removed from the storage group?

There's also some 'official' documentation here which may be of use:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

Could you boot in single user mode and see if the drive appears then?