# USB flash drive not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, flash, usb-drive

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and now my flash drive don't even blink when plugged in! I tested the flash drive on windows PC and it works fin. Tester the usb port on same PC on linux mint (dual boot) it works fin.

**lsblk** command shows:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 147.5G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   976M  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda6   8:6    0 158.7G  0 part /
└─sda7   8:7    0 158.7G  0 part /home
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

when disconnecting and reconnecting the USB flash drive **dmesg** command shows:

```
[132068.186064] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 21
[132070.613840] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[132070.634747] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=063d
[132070.634759] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[132070.634766] usb 3-1: Product: Nano Pro
[132070.634771] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Imation
[132070.634776] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 07B20C039F1207BB
[132070.635151] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Not enough bandwidth. Proposed: 2032098, Max: 1607
[132070.635164] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Not enough bandwidth
[132070.635180] usb 3-1: can't set config #1, error -12
```

**tail /var/log/syslog** before usb plugin:

```
Jun 26 11:33:41 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: message repeated 6 times: [ <warn> nl_recvmsgs() error: (-33) Dump inconsistency detected, interrupted]
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: <info> (eth1): device state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed') [20 10 36]
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: <info> (eth1): cleaning up...
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: <warn> (5) failed to find interface name for index
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: (nm-system.c:766):nm_system_iface_get_flags: runtime check failed: (iface != NULL)
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]: <error> [1403771709.565624] [nm-system.c:768] nm_system_iface_get_flags(): (unknown): failed to get interface link object
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80331.126126] ipheth 3-1:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet now disconnected
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 avahi-daemon[964]: Withdrawing workstation service for eth1.
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:4.2/net/eth1, iface: eth1)
Jun 26 11:35:10 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80332.034212] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

**tail /var/log/syslog** after usb plugin:

```
waqleh@waqleh-Inspiron-3521:/$ tail /var/log/syslog
Jun 26 11:35:09 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 NetworkManager[1138]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:4.2/net/eth1, iface: eth1)
Jun 26 11:35:10 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80332.034212] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.920678] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.941686] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0718, idProduct=063d
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.941698] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.941704] usb 3-4: Product: Nano Pro
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.941709] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Imation
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 kernel: [80359.941714] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 07B20C039F1207BB
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Jun 26 11:35:38 waqleh-Inspiron-3521 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 7 was not an MTP device
```

I have a DELL - Inspiron 15-3521

**uname -a** command shows:

> Linux waqleh-Inspiron-3521 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4
>   21:02:19 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

I even updated the BIOS to latest
**sudo dmidecode -s bios-version**:
A12

Comment: please provide the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @ElderGeek please check the uname-a. I added it to the question

Comment: Wondering if this is a kernel bug... Are you using an external USB hub or plugging directly into the mainboard ports (rear) or front ports? Thank you!

Comment: @ElderGeek it is a laptop it is a side port left and right

Comment: What BIOS version are you running?

Comment: @ElderGeek **sudo dmidecode -s bios-version**: A05

Comment: A05 is quite out of date as A12 is available. this could be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this problem my last resort was to backup all my files format and install a fresh copy of ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS - The latest version for your device is A12 and is available [here](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers)

You'll need to boot into a DOS or Windows environment to install it. You can obtain a DOS boot disk at [this](http://www.bootdisk.com/bootdisk.htm) location.

Comment: That didn't work. now my bios is A12

Comment: I cannot duplicate your issue. Hopefully someone with a DELL - Inspiron 15-3521 can chime in.